# Hibernate-like functionality for C program

Tags: c, assembly

I have a C program spanning across dozens of files. My aim is to write a function that when called will save all the global variables to some file and exit to the OS (command line in windows). Later, I need the program to load the global variables from the file and continue running.

The program is a single threaded exe which does not load any DLLs.

The straightforward way to solve this is to make a list of all the global variables (assuming I'll convert statics to globals) and just dump them to a file. But it is a tedious work, since there are probably hundreds, if not thousands of variables.

Is there any other way around, say dumping the whole data segment and loading it later? Even if I saved the data segment and managed to load it back to RAM, I'll have trouble to associate the program variables to the memory chunks of the data segment.

Comment: Your program has thousands of global variables?! If you really are that hardy about the design, then perhaps look at what Emacs did with `unexec`.

Comment: On Unixes, one way to do is to `mmap` some file and allocate the needed state inside the mmapped file.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Is there something similar for Windows?

Comment: [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761.aspx) but (lacking knowledge of other constraints) this is a terrible solution to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now i've never tried this, and I don't know if it would work but...setjmp / longjmp save the environment and restore it.

I think it would be possible to use setjmp, store the struct(jmp_buf) in a file. Then when the application loads again, load jmp_bug back into RAM and run longjmp.

What do you think?!

Comment: `setjmp` saves only enough information so that `longjmp` can unwind the stack back to where it was when `setjmp` was originally called.